# Problems with case statements in Leaflet's pointToLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create a layer that has different types of business (separated by code properties in the geojson file) but when it executes the pointToLayer below I get an *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'feature' of undefined*. What am i doing wrong?

```
  var allbusinesses = L.geoJson(data, {
    style: allBusinessesStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      switch (feature.properties.code) {
        case "1":
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: "#000"
          });
        ...
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You might have a bit better luck on stack overflow with this question. Can you post sample data & (even better) something like a jsfiddle?

Comment: Is there a fallback case, so that if there is no matching `code`, then `pointToLayer` will still return something? And if you strip out the switch/case statements, so that your `pointToLayer` function simply returns the same type of `circleMarker` for all layers, does it give the same error?

Comment: Thank you both for your help . @nathansnider putting in a default case solved the problem. If you post that as the solution i will credit you with the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your GeoJSON features has a `code` property that is not accounted for by your `case` statements, then your `pointToLayer` function will not return a feature, which can produce the error that you are seeing. Adding a `default` case will prevent this:

```
  var allbusinesses = L.geoJson(data, {
    style: allBusinessesStyle,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      switch (feature.properties.code) {
        case "1":
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: "#000"
          });

        ...

        default:
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: "#fff"
          });
      }
    }
  });
```